# How to store and retrieve multiple data using AsyncStorage

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm new to ReactNative, But I have a bit experience in React.

Here I'm trying to store multiple data in AsyncStorage and trying to retrieve them, But I'm only able to store single data

Code:

```
  state = {
    data: [],
    item: ""
  };

  storeData = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("@storage_Key", JSON.stringify(this.state.item));
    this.getData();
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
  }

  getData = async () => {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@storage_Key");
      let { data, item } = this.state;
      data.push(value);
      this.setState({
        data: data,
        item: ""
      });
    } catch (e) {
      // error reading value
    }
  };
```

Any help or guidance would be appreciated

Comment: whats the output of "value" when you print it to the console? And when do you call storeData?

Comment: storeData calls when I click on a button after typing the input , The typed input is being called in the value

Comment: okay.. whats stored in the value variable in your try block?

Comment: The last value I entered, Like when I enter the values in gets pushed into an array, but when I refresh, only the last one gets displayed

Answer (score 0):

You are only setting and retrieving one item when you use `setItem` and `getItem` respectively.

If you want to store multiple items, you can use [`multiSet`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage#multiset)

```
AsyncStorage.multiSet(['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'value2']);
```

If you want to retrieve multiple items, you can use [`multiGet`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage#multiset)

```
AsyncStorage.multiGet(['key1', 'key2'], (err, items) => {
  console.log({ items });
});
```

Comment: But I'm setting item dynamically, So how will this help? I mean , I'm adding the value (Example :Names of  country) and then displaying that

Answer (score 0):

I have good experience using

[react-native-storage](https://github.com/sunnylqm/react-native-storage)

from what i see from your code you are saving state's item
when you retrieve your data from storage you are putting it in data, is that right?

I suggest you to change the way you arrange the data

you use let { data } = this.state;

if you know you can't set state's data using =
i suggest you to make new variable -> let data and store it with data = value then you can setState({ data: data })

Comment: I did not understand sir, Can you write it down here?